# Tkinter not showing image and no errors

Tags: python, image, tkinter

The code below does not show an image when run.

```py
def show_restaurant_info(event):
    global photo
    selected_restaurant = restaurant_listbox.get(tk.ACTIVE)

    if selected_restaurant:
        restaurant = next((r for r in restaurants if r["name"] == selected_restaurant), None)
        if restaurant:
            info_label.delete('1.0', tk.END)

            restaurant_name = restaurant["name"]
            restaurant_postal_code = restaurant["postal_code"]
            restaurant_cuisine = restaurant["cuisine"]
            restaurant_price = restaurant["price"]
            restaurant_reviews = restaurant["reviews"]
            

            # Display restaurant information
            info_label.insert(tk.END, f"""Name: {restaurant_name}
Postal Code: {restaurant_postal_code}
Cuisine: {restaurant_cuisine}
Price: {restaurant_price}
Reviews: {restaurant_reviews}

""")
            
            # Load and display restaurant image (GIF)
            image_path = restaurant["image"]
            try:
                #photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="image_path")
                photo = Image.open(image_path)
                photo = photo.resize((50, 50))
                # Create a PhotoImage object from the image
                img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
                # Update the label with the new image
                image_label.configure(image=img_tk)
                #image_label.configure(image=photo)
                image_label.image = photo
            except (IOError, tk.TclError):
                # If image file is not found, display a default image
                default_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("default_image.gif"))
                image_label.configure(image=default_image.gif)
                image_label.image = default_image.gif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have saved the wrong image reference `photo`.  You need to save the image reference `img_tk` instead:

```py
def show_restaurant_info(event):
    ...
    try:
       ...
       image_label.image = img_tk    # save reference of image
    except (IOError, tk.TclError):
       # If image file is not found, display a default image
       default_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("default_image.gif"))
       image_label.configure(image=default_image)  # fixed typo default_image.gif
       image_label.image = default_image
```